# random selection of list

Tags: python, dictionary, arraylist, random

I have this list that randomly will choose a different value each time, how can I print the key of the random value that is being selected separately?

```
import random
a_dictionary = {"winter": 10, "summer": 30,"spring":20,"autumn":15}

values = list(a_dictionary.values())

key = list(a_dictionary.keys())

randomx= random.choice( values)

print(randomx)
#print(randomx.key)
```

example: random value =

```
20 

spring
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
import random

dict = {
  "winter" : 10, 
  "summer" : 30, 
  "spring":  20, 
  "autumn" : 15
}

values = list(dict.values())

keys = list(dict.keys())

random = random.choice(values)

print(random)

print(keys[values.index(random)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try:

```py
key, value = random.choice(list(a_dictionary.items()))
```

Alternatively, if you have no control over the process that does the choice picking (i.e. you just have the value), you can use a reverse dict:

```py
rev_dict = {v: k for k, v in a_dictionary.items()}

# and later, say your randomx is 20
>>> rev_dict[randomx]
'spring'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.items()`

```
import random
a_dictionary = {"winter": 10, "summer": 30,"spring":20,"autumn":15}

print(random.choice(list(a_dictionary.items()))) # prints ('winter', 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate over the list of VALUES, but over the list of ITEMS:

```
season, number = random.choice(list(a_dictionary.items()))
```